# How do you figure out what is causing '/login' to be called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I was looking at the Firebug output for my index page and noticed that my `/login` handler is getting called at some point during the execution of the index page. It doesn't redirect to the `/login` page though for some reason.

But I can't tell which resource is triggering `/login` to be called. Is there some way of outputting the source of the call to the handler in Spring 3.0 MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by turning up the logging and checking out the log on the application\web server.